# How to get the name of submit button created dynamically on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating HTML button dynamically using jquery and adding that into a Panel .The number of button will vary as per the value in the database table.Now as per my requirement i need to get the name of submit button as soon as i click any of the button but i am not able to do it.
Here is my jquery code..

```
obj = data.d;
var obj1 = obj.split(',');
for (var j = 0; j < obj1.length; j++) {
var h = "";
h += "<input type='button' class='btn btn-custom ' id='b1' value=" + obj1[j] + ">";
$('#p1').append(h);
}
```

and here is my button click event which is not working as required..

```
 $('#b1').click(function () {
 var ss = $(this).val();
 alert("ss ");
 });
```

Please help me ..Thanks

Comment: Give the elements a class that is not used elsewhere (e.g.`my-new-class`). Then update your event code to `$('.my-new-class').click(function () { var ss = $(this).val(); alert("ss "); });`

Comment: @PhilippM Ok.what should be there in the class?

Comment: You can choose a name yourself. Just make sure it makes sense for good readability.